# vscode emmet not auto suggesting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

All my other projects work but I can't figure out what is different between this vanilla example and the others which have a lot of npm packages in them.

This does not autosuggest when entering

```
export type THello = string;
export interface Props {
  hello: string
}
const myvar: Pro // <- expect to see autosuggest happen here...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript-tslint-plugin": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
      }
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
    },
    "watch": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true, // problem with visual studio code import module resolutions if file does not sit inside src/
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export type THello = string;
export interface Props {
  hello: string
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to Emmet, it is the VSCode IntelliSense. Have you tried triggering autocomplete with Ctrl-Space?

Comment: @iz_ thanks for reply. Oh interesting. Yes it just shows Loading.... And no auto suggestion.

Comment: I'm not too sure what your problem could be, try restarting the typescript server or restart vscode.

Comment: yeah done that no change

Comment: @iz_ see my discovery below. Concerning bug.

Comment: Seems strange, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you believe it is this single line that is breaking my vscode emmet from working

**babel.config.js**

```js
console.log(1); // <- this console log is breaking vscode emmet auto suggest.
module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel']
};
```

See created repo to demonstrate problem
https://github.com/inspiraller/vscode-emmet

Comment: Emmet is a tool to generate HTML using CSS syntax. What does it have to do with Typescript?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález indeed. I suspect there is some conflict between babel and tsconfig